# There is a well ordering of the class of all finite sequences of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I am trying to solve this exercise from Jech's book on set theory:

> **Ex. 3.6:** There is a well ordering of the class of all finite sequences of ordinals such that for each $\alpha$, the set of all finite sequences in $\omega_{\alpha}$ is an initial segment and its order-type is $\omega_{\alpha}$.
>
> **Definition:** If $W$ is a well ordered set and $u \in W$, then the set $\{ x \in W \mid  x < u \}$ is an initial segment in W

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

For $f,g\in\operatorname{Ord}^{<\omega}$ define
$n_{f,g}$ to be the value $\min\{n\mid f(n)\neq g(n)\}$ (if $f\neq g$).  Now you can
define $f<g$ to mean this:
\begin{align*}
&\max\operatorname{ran}(f) < \max\operatorname{ran}(g)\\
\lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) < \operatorname{dom}(g))\\
\lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) = \operatorname{dom}(g)
\land f(n_{f,g}) < g(n_{f,g}))
\end{align*}
This is the well-ordering you're looking for.  Now prove that it does what it's supposed to do!

**Hint:** Let $A_g$ be the initial segment $\{ f \in \operatorname{Ord}^{<\omega} \mid f < g \}$.  It is easy to see that for every $\alpha$ the set $A_{\{(0,\alpha)\}}$ is equal to $\alpha^{<\omega}$; specifically - replacing $\alpha$ with $\omega_\alpha$ -, each $\omega_\alpha^{<\omega}$ is an initial segment in $<$.

Because of $|\omega_\alpha|\leq|\omega_\alpha^{<\omega}|$, the order type of $\omega_\alpha^{<\omega}$ can't be smaller than $\omega_\alpha$.  Now suppose there's a smallest $\alpha$ such that the order type of $\omega_\alpha^{<\omega}$ is strictly *greater* than $\omega_\alpha$ and show that this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I am thinking of transfinite induction on $\alpha$. Is the following ok for the basis of the onduction? Let $\alpha = 0$. Let $g: \omega^{< \omega} \rightarrow \omega$ be an isomorphism. Then, $\{ f(u) \in \omega | u \in \omega^{< \omega} \}$ is the required initial segment.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What's the role of $g$?  Where does $\alpha$ appear in all of this?  Why is your initial segment not a set of finite sequences of ordinals?  This all seems rather confused.  (And have you already convinced yourself that my $<$ is indeed a well-ordering to begin with?)

Comment: I am trying to "create" an initial segment inside $\omega$. I know that $|\omega^{< \omega}| = |\omega|$. I know that if two well-ordered sets has the same cardinality then there is an order-preserving function $g$ which is one-to-one and onto. If this is not the right basis for the induction, then, how should this basis be written?

Comment: See the hint I added above.

Comment: I have started writing the proof here below. At the bottom, I pointed out something in your clue that is not clear to me. Could you clarify that for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We will show first that $<$ is a well order:

1. **antysimetry:** Let $f<g$. Then, 
   \begin{align*}
   &\max\operatorname{ran}(f) < \max\operatorname{ran}(g)\\
   \lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) < \operatorname{dom}(g))\\
   \lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) = \operatorname{dom}(g)
   \land f(n_{f,g}) < g(n_{f,g}))
   \end{align*}

Suppose now that $g < f$. 
Then, $\max\operatorname{ran}(g) < \max\operatorname{ran}(f)$ will contradict lines 1,2,3 in the definition of $'<'$. $(\max\operatorname{ran}(g) = \max\operatorname{ran}(f) \land \operatorname{dom}(g) < \operatorname{dom}(f))$ will contradict lines 1,2,3 in the definition, and also $(\max\operatorname{ran}(g) = \max\operatorname{ran}(f) \land \operatorname{dom}(g) = \operatorname{dom}(f)
\land f(n_{f,g}) < g(n_{f,g}))$ will contradict lines 1,2,3 in the definition. So, we cannot have $g<f$.

2. **Transitivity:** Suppose that $f<g$ and $g<h$. Then, we have, 
   $\begin{align*}
   &\max\operatorname{ran}(f) < \max\operatorname{ran}(g)\\
   \lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) < \operatorname{dom}(g))\\
   \lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(f) = \max\operatorname{ran}(g) \land \operatorname{dom}(f) = \operatorname{dom}(g)
   \land f(n_{f,g}) < g(n_{f,g}))
   \end{align*}$

and also

$\begin{align*}
&\max\operatorname{ran}(g) < \max\operatorname{ran}(h)\\
\lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(g) = \max\operatorname{ran}(h) \land \operatorname{dom}(g) < \operatorname{dom}(h))\\
\lor&(\max\operatorname{ran}(g) = \max\operatorname{ran}(h) \land \operatorname{dom}(g) = \operatorname{dom}(h)
\land g(n_{h,g}) < h(n_{h,g}))
\end{align*}$

If $max(ran(f))<max(ran(g))$ then $max(ran(f))<max(ran(h))$. If $max(ran(f))=max(ran(g))$ and $dom(f) < dom(g)$ then either $max(ran(f))=max(ran(h))$ or $dom(f) < dom(h)$.

checking the other properties of $'<'$ similarly, shows, that $f<h$.

3. **totality:** given $f \neq g$, we cannot have,  $ran(f) = ran(g)$ and $dom(f) = dom(g)$ and $f(n) = g(n)$ for each $n$, since this would imply, $f=g$.

Let $A_g$ be the initial segment $\{ f \in \operatorname{Ord}^{<\omega} \mid f < g \}$.   We will show first that:

> For every $\alpha$ the set $A_{\{(0,\alpha)\}}$ is equal to $\alpha^{<\omega}$; specifically - replacing $\alpha$ with $\omega_\alpha$ -, each $\omega_\alpha^{<\omega}$ is an initial segment in $<$.

**Question: what is the meaning of the notation $A_{(0,\alpha)}$?**

Comment: It was defined in the line before that: "Let $A_g$ be the initial segment..."  In this case, $g=\{(0,\alpha)\}$, i.e. the function with domain $1=\{0\}$ and range $\{\alpha\}$.

Comment: Note that I didn't write $A_{(0,\alpha)}$ as you did but $A_{\{(0,\alpha)\}}$.

Comment: ok thank you. I will think about it a bit more and will edit my answer to my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The exercise says that "... an initial segment and its **order-type** is $\omega_\alpha$.", not that "... an initial segment and its **cardinal** is $\omega_\alpha$.".

I'm not sure, but my solution is:

$\quad$We define:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\alpha_0,\ldots&\rangle\prec\langle\beta_0,\ldots\rangle
\leftrightarrow\\
&\text{there is }k\text{ such that }\\
&\qquad\alpha_k<\beta_k\text{ and }\alpha_i=\beta_i
\text{ for all }i<k,\\
\langle\alpha_i:i<m&\rangle<\langle\beta_i:i<n\rangle\leftrightarrow\\
&\text{either }\sum_{i<m}\alpha_i+m <
\sum_{i<n}\beta_i+n\\
&\text{or }\sum_{i<m}\alpha_i+m=\sum_{i<n}\beta_i+n\\
&\qquad\text{ and }
\langle\alpha_i:i<m\rangle\prec\langle\beta_i:i<n\rangle.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
 $\quad$Let $X$ be the class of all finite sequences
of ordinals. The relation $<$ defined above is a linear ordering of $X$. Moreover, if $S\subset X$ is nonempty,
then $S$ has a least element. If we let
$\Gamma(\alpha)=$ the order-type of the set
$\{\beta\in X:\beta<\alpha\}$ for $\alpha\in X$,
then $\Gamma$ is a one-to-one mapping of $X$ onto $Ord$.
Note that for a finite sequence $\alpha$ in $\omega$,
$\Gamma(\alpha)\in\omega$,
and so $\langle\omega\rangle$ is the least element $\alpha$ of $X$
such that $\alpha$ is not a finite sequence in $\omega$; thus
$\Gamma(\langle\omega\rangle)=\omega$.
 $\quad$Let $\gamma(\alpha)=\Gamma(\langle\alpha\rangle)$.
Note that $\gamma(\alpha)$ is an increasing function of $\alpha$, and
also that since each infinite cardinal is indecomposable,
by definition of $(X,<)$, $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)$ is the set of all
finite sequences in $\omega_\alpha$. Let $\eta(\alpha)=$ the order-type
of the set of all finite sequences in $\alpha$. Then
$\gamma(\alpha)\le\eta(\alpha)$ and $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)
=\eta(\omega_\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$. We show that
$\gamma(\omega_\alpha)=\omega_\alpha$ by induction
of $\alpha$. This is true for $\alpha=0$. Thus let $\alpha$ be the least
ordinal such that $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)\ne\omega_\alpha$.
Since $\gamma$ is increasing, $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)\ge\omega_\alpha$;
thus $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)>\omega_\alpha$,
and so there is a sequence $\beta$ such that
$\Gamma(\beta)=\omega_\alpha$ and $\beta<\langle\omega_\alpha\rangle$.
Then there is an ordinal $\delta$ such that
$\beta<\langle\delta\rangle<\langle\omega_\alpha\rangle$; thus
$\Gamma(\beta)=\omega_\alpha<\gamma(\delta)\le\eta(\delta)$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $\aleph_\alpha\le|\eta(\delta)|$ $=$ $|\eta(|\delta|)|
\le\eta(|\delta|)$.
But since $\delta<\omega_\alpha$, by the minimality of $\alpha$,
$\eta(|\delta|)=|\delta|<\aleph_\alpha$.
A contradiction. Finally, by definition of $\gamma$,
for each nonzero limit ordinal $\alpha$, $\gamma(\omega_\alpha)=
\text{sup }\{\gamma(\omega_\xi):\xi<\alpha\}=\omega_\alpha$.