# Order type of the set of finite sequences in a cardinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is a follow-up question of the following

[There is a well ordering of the class of all finite sequences of ordinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934852/there-is-a-well-ordering-of-the-class-of-all-finite-sequences-of-ordinals)

I have two questions regarding this. Firstly, is there a nice way to find a minimum of any non-empty subset X of Ord$^{<\omega}$; right now my proof is a bit unprecise, I take the minimal value of the maximal ranges, then the minimal domain, and then I minimize the values at that domain one by one. It's very tedious to even describe this let alone prove it.

Secondly, and this is my major issue, I can't work out why the order type of the set of finite sequences in $\omega_{\alpha}$ is $\omega_{\alpha}$ itself in this ordering. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding your first question, your approach seems like the best one to me. 

Regarding your second question, you were given a hint for this. Have a look at the hint and then tell me where you get stuck.

Comment: I can't really see how I can use the order type of $\omega_{\beta}^{<\omega}$ for $\beta< \alpha$ to conclude anything about $\omega_{\alpha}^{<\omega}$'s order type; I tried distinguishing between the case where $\alpha$ is a limit and the case where it is a successor, but I found it very hard to count the sequences in $\omega_{\alpha}^{< \omega}$ which are after the ones occuring in $\omega_{\beta}^{< \omega}$.

Comment: Just suppose that the order type of $\omega_{\alpha}^{<\omega}$ was greater than $\omega_{\alpha}$. Then it would have a proper initial fragment order isomorphic to $\omega_{\alpha}$. Have a think about what that would mean if you are assuming the transfinite induction hypothesis.